# What exception is thrown while creating a file in java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Filewrite {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            String content="This is my world";
            File f=new File("D:/abc.txt");
        }catch(IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation of the above code gives an error:

```
IO exception is never thrown by this corresponding try block.
```

What exception may be thrown while creating a file?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? I don't think it can be any clearer.

Comment: Try removing the `IOException`. Does it give error?

Comment: ur code "File f=new File("D:/abc.txt");" does not creates a file so there is no need of try-catch block. Now if u add this line: f.createNewFile(); this will create a file without any contents in it and the compilation error will be gone

Answer (score 1):

From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> **Throws:**
>   NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null

When you want to see what Exceptions are being thrown by a method (constructor in this case), you can search in Java Docs, or if you are using Eclipse IDE, put cursor over the method, and press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

`IOException` comes when

> Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is
>   the general class of  exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O
>   operations.

in your code you are just creating a file object. It throws a `NullPointerException` if the path is null.

If you want to do any operations with that file like read, write etc... it throws `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException`

Answer (score 0):

The error caused because your code block will never throw an IOException.
IOException will be thrown mostly when doing IO operations on files or other sources

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

When ever you try to catch checked exception only which will never be thrown by your code in try block then compiler will always give you error of compilation.
In this case you are not performing any file operation(creation, reading, writing).
So your code will never throw any io exception which is checked exception.
You can't catch that exception which will never be thrown by your try block.

**How To Fix**

You can fix by removing io-exception from catch block then code will compile fine.